# Debian kernel upgrade issue

Tags: debian, kernel

I was checking my ****Debian 11** bullseye** kernel if i have fix for **Dirty Pipe vulnerability**. Seems that kernel version 5.10.102 has the fix for that.
Problem is that i cannot get upgrade for that kernel version. At least with `apt-get update` command.
Do i have to manually upgrade my kernel or is there some repository which i have to add to my `sources.list`?
Also `apt-get update` or `apt-get dist-upgrade` does not give OS upgrade to version 11.2 which seems to be latest version of Debian. `uname -rs` gives me **Linux 5.10.0-11-amd64**

Answer (score 0):

The fixed kernel version (5.10.103-1) is available in the Bullseye security repository. Add this line to your `sources.list`:

```
deb http://deb.debian.org/debian-security/ bullseye-security main
```

Comment: Finally got time to try this. Unfortunally this did not do the trick. I have above repo in `sources.list` but highest kernel version i get is `5.10.0-13-amd64`